# Given two positive integers N and X, where N is the number of total patients and X is the time duration(in minutes) after which a new patient arrives

Tags: javascript, python

Given two positive integers N and X, where N is the number of total patients and X is the time duration(in minutes) after which a new patient arrives. Also, doctor will give only 10 minutes to each patient. The task is to calculate the time (in minutes) the last patient needs to wait.

Input:

The first line of input contains the number of test cases T. The next subsequent lines denote the total number of patients N and time interval X(in minutes) in which the next patients are visiting.

Output:

Output the waiting time of last patient.

Constraints:

1 <= T <= 100

0 <= N <= 100

0 <= X <= 30

Example:

Input:

5

4 5

5 3

6 5

7 6

8 2

Output:

15

28

25

24

56

need in javascript. I know the python code. but needs to convert into javascript. anyone can help me.

```js
n=int(input())
for i in range(n):
    t=0
    a,b=map(int,input().split())
    if a==1:
        print(t)
    else:
        
        t=(a-1)*(10-b)
        print(t)
```

Answer (score 0):

If by Javascript you mean Node.js, this is the code. Due to Node.js's asynchronous nature, handling user input is a bit tedious.

```
const readline = require("readline");

async function solve(n) {
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {  // for i in range(n)
        let t = 0;
        let inputs = (await readInput()).split(" ");
        let a = inputs[0]; let b = inputs[1];  // a, b = map ...

        if (a === 1) {
            console.log(t);
        } else {
            t = (a - 1) * (10 - b);
            console.log(t);
        }

    }
}

function readInput() {
    // Creates an interface for input and output
    const rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: process.stdin,
        output: process.stdout,
    });

    // Returns the input
    return new Promise((resolve) => rl.question("Input: ", (ans) => {
        rl.close();
        resolve(ans);
    }))
}

async function main() {
    await solve(await readInput());
}

main().then(_ => console.log("Done"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    class Main {
static int waittime(int n ,int x){
    int wait1 = x*(n-1);  //total time till the last patient arrived
int wait2 = (n-1)*10; //total time doctor take to see all patient except last
    int wait = wait2-wait1;//total wait time
    if(wait<0)
      wait = 0;
 return wait;
}
public static void main (String[] args) {
                  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
                  int t = sc.nextInt(); // t is total test case
                  int n ,x;
                  int arr[] = new int[t];
                  for(int i=0;i<t;i++){
                      n = sc.nextInt();
                      x = sc.nextInt();
                      arr[i] = waittime(n,x); // storing wait time for each 
                                               //  test case 
                  }
                  for(int i=0;i<t;i++){
                      System.out.println(arr[i]);
                  }
}
```

}

Comment: Please add comments to explain your answer